# React router path different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image]

How can we set footerNew if path is example2 and footer if we have path example. How can we change component with different path . I know this could have been done with the path mixing but that has been deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only diff you have between your routes is the pathname. So :

```
<div className="...">
    {props.context.router.getCurrentPathname() === '/example' ? <Footer /> : </FooterNew />}
</div>
```

Comment: This thing works but i have a condition under footer also to change some text , how can i get to the child component.

Comment: // footerNew     Var text ="
If(pathname = '/example'){
Text=<p>text 1</p>
}
Else{
Text=<p>text 2</p>

}

return (
 <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
  {text }
 </div>
)